# How to recover WordPress Adress(URL)

Tags: 404-error, options, directory, localhost

I installed WordPress in localhost. I changed the WordPress Address from the general settings. After that none of the previous pages appears. Instead, a "Page Not Found" error page is appearing. 
I tried to change WordPress Address into previous one, but it doesn't happen.

Now how can I recover the previous pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit file `wp-config.php` in root & define site url and home url:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

And go to admin dashboard and update permalink (Settings => Permalinks => Update).